# How to enable browsing cache for my website?

Tags: page-speed, cache-control

I have created a website and the speed of my website is very slow. i want to enable browser cache for my website how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use a CDN like Cloudflare.  They will automatically cache your static resources, and serve them over HTTP2 as well if you want.  This should have an immediate effect on the speed of your site.

Comment: Would this cache the resources on the client side or does it cache on cloudflare servers?

Comment: Both, depending on Cloudflare settings.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to your FTP server, create *.htaccess* file and paste one of these codes in it:

### Adding Expire Headers

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# 1 YEAR - doesn't change often
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A31536000
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK - possible to be changed, unlikely
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
</FilesMatch>

# 3 HOUR - core content, changes quickly
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A10800
</FilesMatch>
```

### Using max-age headers

```
# 1 YEAR
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 3 HOUR
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=10800"
</FilesMatch>

# NEVER CACHE - notice the extra directives
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php|cgi|pl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Both of these types cache files with the extension that is in parentheses "()".
You can change these file extensions if you feel some files are going to be edited more frequently. Don't forget to split them with the vertical bar "|"

You can check if your caching works on [Redbot.org](http://redbot.org)

More about HTTP caching [here](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)

Comment: Just to clarify, both these methods set `Cache-Control` `max-age` headers, it's just that using mod_expires (the first example) _also_ sets the `Expires` header for backwards compatibility. (The `max-age` header takes priority in all modern browsers.)